# Session Variables Laravel

Tags: laravel, session-variables

I am new in working with Laravel, currently I am working with sessions.
I got a bit confused with the syntax on how to save session variables.
¿Could you help me?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add global variables all you have to do is

```
session()->regenerate();

session()->put('name', $value);
```

and that should add it to your session variables